# is it possible to turn on a discord.js bot by sending a message?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have recently created a discord bot and am currently having a ton of fun! I can turn it off by sending a message on my server but I still wonder if there is any way to turn it on by doing the same.
All I want is to send something like "bot on" in my server and make the bot turn on.

Answer (score 1):

The bot must be turned on to receive messages so that's not possible. However, you can start a bot that will start your other bot when a message is received.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simpler way to do it would to make one command be sort of a toggle, so that when it is sent the bot starts replying/interacting, and when sent again discontinues. The easiest way to signify the status would be with the Activity Status (the text) or the regular Status (do not disturb compared to online).